# Create method within method in a new Class in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have typescript project and more specific and Angular application.

I have my Class called Test (you can assume its a component in angular) and it has access to http service which is usually used like this.http('/endpoint').subscribe(response => {});

I need to add some logic in between and break it down into separate methods (the code is a little bit more complicated than in my example).

```
export class Test {

init() {
    this.http.get('/endpoint').map(this.transform);
}

transform(data) {
    // more logic here in isolated scope

    this.accessOutside(data); // I cannot access this method, isolated scope.
    // How to break down some logic into separate methods to access them
    // or how to create it new method within method?

    return data
}

accessOutside(data) {
    // more logic
}
```

}

When i call this.http.get('/endpoint').map(this.transform) my "transform" method is isolated and has no access to other methods within Test class, but how to access it or how to create method within transform method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass the `transform` function into the `map` function like this

`this.http.get('/endpoint').map(this.transform);`

you are passing a copy of the `transform` function, which has no concept of `this`. As a result, when the `map` function calls the copy of the `transform` function, it's context will default to the `window` object. So in the copy of the `transform` method, it will be looking for a function called `accessOutside` on the `window` object.

The simplest way to fix this problem is to use a lambda function as follows:

`this.http.get('/endpoint').map(data => this.transform(data));`

As [arrow funcitons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) have access to the scope of the context they are defined in, when `map` calls the arrow function, `this` will refer to your instance of `Test` and not `window`

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what i wanted. Thank you!